# When retrieving MySQL date, it becomes date and time

Tags: c#, mysql, xampp

I would like to ask about why when I retrieve my data from my database, the date becomes date and time.

This is my database:

[image: Database Table format]

This is my code C#:

```
private void runQuery()
{
    string query = txtQuery.Text;

    if(query == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Empty Query");
        return;
    }

    string strSQLConnection = "datasource = 127.0.0.1;port = 3306; username = root; password =; database =inventory";
    MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(strSQLConnection);
    MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbConnection);
    sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 60;

    try
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        MySqlDataReader myReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if(myReader.HasRows)
        {
            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                lstQuery.Items.Add(myReader.GetString(0) + " | " + myReader.GetString(1) +" | " + myReader.GetString(2));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lstQuery.Items.Add("Query successfully executed!");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Query error: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

The database:

[image: Data in Database]

Comment: I not sure which information i left out, please inform me and I will add it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET, there's no date-only type. The type that handles date value is called `DateTime` and it represents both date and time. Therefore, when you retrieve the date value from the database, it gets converted to a `DateTime` value with the time part being `00:00:00` and it's then converted to a string by the `GetString()` method. What you should do is use `DateTime.ToString()` to format your date however you like.

Try something like this:

```
string formattedDate = myReader.GetDateTime(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

---

### References:

- [`SqlDataReader.GetDateTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime).
- [`DateTime.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring).